# Wrong scrollTop on change direction

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel

I've got strange behaviour  with `scrollTop` on `mouse wheel` event, can you explain me why so happens?

> When `mouse wheel` direction changes, `scrollTop` continue calc in previous direction by one iteration... i wanna get actual `scrollTop` on `mouse wheel` event  with change direction.

```
scrollTop: 0; deltaY: 200 (Dn)
scrollTop: 100; deltaY: 200 (Dn)
scrollTop: 200; deltaY: 200 (Dn)
scrollTop: 300; deltaY: 200 (Dn)
scrollTop: 400; deltaY: 200 (Dn)
scrollTop: 500; deltaY: -200 (Up) <<< direction changed but srollTop grows,  expected value 300 not 500  
scrollTop: 400; deltaY: -200 (Up)
scrollTop: 300; deltaY: -200 (Up)
```

how can i fix it?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfpx384c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wheel` event is fired before the `scroll` event (effectively - before the change to the scroll) so the `scrollTop` you are logging is the value it started with when the event was triggered (when you scroll the wheel)

Comment: Ouch, i need to use scroll event instead wheel... thank you!